# Silverlight binding a HeaderTemplate

Tags: silverlight, binding

I have an accordion control, here's the xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="CasesPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit"    
mc:Ignorable="d"
d:DesignHeight="1050" d:DesignWidth="1600">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="AccordionItemHeaderTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CaseName}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Border Margin="20,20,0,20" Background="White" BorderBrush="Transparent" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="10">
<toolkit:Accordion Margin="30"  Name="CasesListAccordion" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource AccordionContainerStyleLawBot}" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" SelectionMode="ZeroOrOne" SelectionSequence="CollapseBeforeExpand" Style="{StaticResource NewAccordionStyle}"
                   ItemsSource="{Binding}" AccordionButtonStyle="{StaticResource AccordionButtonStyleNotEdited}"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="Black" Background ="White"
         SelectedItemsChanged="CasesListAccordion_SelectedItemsChanged">
    </toolkit:Accordion>
</Border>
```

In my User control resources, I also have a data template which I want to use for headertemplate in each accordion item.

The accordion items are populated from the code, I do this because I receive them dynamically.

Here's the code:

```
foreach(ECase Case in Cases)
        {
            //Create an accordion item
            AccordionItem item = new AccordionItem();
            item.Tag = Case;
            item.DataContext = Case;
            item.HeaderTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.Resources["AccordionItemHeaderTemplate"]; 



        }
```

The class ECase has a Member called CaseName .
I bind this member in the xaml in the datatemplate to the textblock:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="AccordionItemHeaderTemplate">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CaseName}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

And I also assign the DataContext of the accordionItem to the ECase:

```
item.DataContext = Case;
```

And still the CaseName is not displayed in the accordion item's header.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should assign the object to the Header property instead.

Try

```
item.Header = Case;
```